# Parsing smpp dlr report

Tags: javascript, node.js, smpp

I am using node-smpp for sending SMS. Everything works fine and no issues so far. My doubt is how to efficiently parse a DLR response. for example, I got the following DLR response

```
id:355e917d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:2012191607 done date:2012191607 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:Tester
```

I need the **stat** field from the above response. I tried split function with space and colon. Is there any better way to get the **stat** field from the response?.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Regex Expression with "stat:" and " " as prefix and postfix to get the value

Answer (score 0):

little bit out of date, but anyway, you can try this regex

```
const regexToParseSms = new RegExp(/^id:([^ ]+) sub:(\w{1,3}) dlvrd:(\w{1,3}) submit date:(\w{10,12}) done date:(\w{10,12}) stat:([A-Z ]{7}) err:(\w{1,4}) text:(.*)$/, 'si');

const parsedSms = regexToParseSms.exec('id:355e917d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:2012191607 done date:2012191607 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:Tester');
```

expected parsedSms to be array:

```
[ "id:355e917d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:2012191607 done date:2012191607 stat:DELIVRD err:000 text:Tester", "355e917d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", "001", "001", "2012191607", "2012191607", "DELIVRD", "000", "Tester" ]
```